# Overwrite Python 3 maxheap

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to overwrite "max heap " in Python 3.
It's not working. I've already rewritten the **gt** comparator.

It should have a straightforward way to achieve this in Python, right?

The output of the first 2 items are `'i', 'coding'`
However, the expectation items are 'i, love'

Which doesn't make sense at all. Not sure why the Python heapq module is so confusing.

```
# ["i", "love", "leetcode", "i", "love", "coding"]

from collections import defaultdict
from heapq import heappush, _heappop_max, _heapify_max

class node(object):
    def __init__(self, cnt, word):
        self.cnt = cnt
        self.word = word

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.cnt < other.cnt

    def __gt__(self, other):
        return self.cnt > other.cnt

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.cnt ==  other.cnt

class Solution(object):
    def topKFrequent(self, words, k):
        """
        :type words: List[str]
        :type k: int
        :rtype: List[str]
        """
        heaped_words = []
        _heapify_max(heaped_words)
        counts = defaultdict(lambda: 0)
        results = []
        for i in words:
            counts[i] += 1
        for word, count in counts.items():
            heappush(heaped_words, node(count, word))

        while heaped_words:
            item = _heappop_max(heaped_words)
            if item:
                results.append(item.word)

        return results
```

Comment: Using `heappush` which is actually intended for a min-heap with the API function `_heapify_max` is bound to give unwanted results.

Comment: @MosesKoledoye lol. you also don't know how to use heapq module right? I tried. `
    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.cnt < other.cnt

    def __gt__(self, other):
        return self.cnt > other.cnt
` Noth of them are not working. Such a confusing module :(

Comment: @MosesKoledoye is it meaning, Python can not do max_heap by using `_heapfy_max`?. If so, I'm so surprised about Python :(

Comment: Haha, good luck with finding your answer :P

Comment: thank you so much though. Just really surprised that Python has no easy way to implement max_heap lol

Comment: Try inverting the priority (or counts) i.e. `node(-count, word)` using a negative sign and use the normal min-heap push and pop functions; you now have a max-heap. As per `_heapify_max `, it's not actually doing anything here as you're calling it on an empty list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use the API functions for `_heapmax_...` to implement a max-heap. Instead, you can simply swap the priority with which items are pushed on the heap by changing the sign on each node i.e. `node(-count, word)`.

Then your max-heap easily becomes:

```
from collections import Counter

def topKFrequent(words, k):
        """
        :type words: List[str]
        :type k: int
        :rtype: List[str]
        """
        counts = Counter(words)
        heaped_words = []
        for word, count in counts.items():
            heappush(heaped_words, node(-count, word))
        return [heappop(heaped_words).word for _ in range(k)]


lst = ["i", "love", "leetcode", "i", "love", "coding"]
print(topKFrequent(lst, 2))
# ['i', 'love']
```

Note that if *k* is going to be almost as large as the size of the input list, you could provide a branching instruction within your function to simply call `sorted` on the list and return the sorted list; this would be far more efficient than multiple push and pops.

Comment: thanks for this smart solution to put the count in a negative way! brillirant!

Comment: @Dummy OTOH, you may consider using `heapq.nlargest` to replace all of the code entirely.